# WPF application crash on non Windows 10 environment without VS15

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, visual-studio-2015

I compile WPF application on computer with windows 10 and VS15 Enterprise and it runs fine.
When I run it on any other computer without this configuration (Win10+VS15) in crashes on startup.
In Windows Events i find this exception information:

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentException
Stack:
at MS.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagerWrapper.GetStream(System.String)
at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.EnsureResourceLocationSet()
at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetContentTypeCore()
at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.get_ContentType()
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri, Boolean)
at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
at System.Windows.Application.<_ctor>b__0(System.Object)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
at TempMonitor.App.Main()
```

In occurs in autogenerated code in App.g.cs so I can't debug it. And I can't understand why this error occurs.
Does anyone have same this issue?

UPD:
Found an error: in AssemblyInfo.cs was wrong locale :-)

Comment: Probably the system you are trying to run the application doesn't have necessary .net framework installed.

Comment: Have, I check this issue.